# wordpress dashboard is too slow . its same pages are taking 10 min approx

Tags: dashboard

I am building a website only 2 products is added now but dashboard is very slow . Even i am not able to edit home page with elementor because it is not opening properly . while other pages are also very slow  it take 3-4 minute .
        please help me ..I have been fedup . I thought wordpress will work better .

Answer (score 0):

This is due to plugin or theme complications on your website. SO try to `deactivate` all the `plugins` and active one by one to figure out the issue. Also, check console if there are any errors

Also, check with the default theme.